# winutils spark windows installation env_variable

Tags: windows, git, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-standalone

I am trying to install Spark 1.6.1 on windows 10 and so far I have done the following...

1. Downloaded spark 1.6.1, unpacked to some directory and then set SPARK_HOME
2. Downloaded scala 2.11.8, unpacked to some directory and then set SCALA_HOME
3. Set the _JAVA_OPTION env variable
4. Downloaded the winutils from https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils.git by just downloading the zip directory and then set HADOOP_HOME env variable. (Not sure if this was incorrect, I could not clone the directory because of permission denied).

When I go to spark home and run bin\spark-shell I get

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I must be missing something, I don't see how I could be running the bash scripts anyway from windows environment.  But hopefully I don't need to understand just to get this working.  I have been following this guy's tutorial - https://hernandezpaul.wordpress.com/2016/01/24/apache-spark-installation-on-windows-10/ . Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to download the winutils executable, not source code.

You can download it [here](http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/hdp-win-alpha/winutils.exe), or if you really want the entire Hadoop distribution you can find the 2.6.0 binaries [here](http://www.barik.net/archive/2015/01/19/172716/). Then, you need to set `HADOOP_HOME` to the directory containing winutils.exe.

Also, **make sure the directory you place Spark in is a directory that doesn't contain whitespaces**, this is extremely important otherwise it won't work.

Once you've set it up, you don't start `spark-shell.sh`, you start `spark-shell.cmd`:

```
C:\Spark\bin>spark-shell
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Using Spark's repl log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults-repl.properties
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel("INFO")
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.10.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_91)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
Spark context available as sc.
16/05/18 19:31:56 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/C:/Spark/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/C:/Spark/bin/../lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar."
16/05/18 19:31:56 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.api.jdo" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/C:/Spark/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/C:/Spark/bin/../lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar."
16/05/18 19:31:56 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/C:/Spark/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/C:/Spark/bin/../lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar."
16/05/18 19:31:56 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
16/05/18 19:31:56 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
16/05/18 19:32:01 WARN ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.2.0
16/05/18 19:32:01 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
16/05/18 19:32:07 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/C:/Spark/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/C:/Spark/bin/../lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar."
16/05/18 19:32:07 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.api.jdo" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/C:/Spark/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/C:/Spark/bin/../lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar."
16/05/18 19:32:07 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/C:/Spark/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/C:/Spark/bin/../lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar."
16/05/18 19:32:07 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
16/05/18 19:32:08 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
16/05/18 19:32:12 WARN ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.2.0
16/05/18 19:32:12 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
SQL context available as sqlContext.

scala>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, that space in the path did help!  I have another error relating to the building of spark when I run spark-shell "Failed to find Spark assembly JAR.
You need to build Spark before running this program."  I will check for help on this one.  I'm glad I posted this question, I hadnt thought that it was just a space issue but it makes sense since robust command line parsing wouldnt be of concern with a utility like this

Comment: @Mike I agree, but that's what we have :\.

Comment: Hi Yuval, is that the 32 bit or 64 bit winutils? I am still getting an error that I trying to chase down, when it tries to initialize SQL context, right in the middle of spark-shell booting up.  It gives me the following warning "Your hostname, DELE-6565 resolves to a  loopback/non-reachable address: fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:c0a8:103%net1, but we couldn't     find any external IP address!" and then throws and exception... 
"java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException."  I'm trying to trace down the cause of this.

Comment: @mike The winutils exe I'm not sure. The hadoop dist is 64 bit. Can you create a new question and put the link here in the comments?

Comment: Sure here it is!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37334757/spark-windows-installation-java-error

Comment: point HADOOP_HOME to particular directory and then create bin directory inside it then put winutils.exe in that directory. Otherwise you will still face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

on windows you need to explicitly specify as where to locate the hadoop binaries.

below are steps to set up spark-scala standalone application.

1. download winutil.exe and place it to some folder/directory under bin folder say c:\hadoop\bin

complete path look like c:\hadoop\bin\winutil.exe

2. now while creating the sparkSession we need to specify this path. Refer the code snippet below:

   package com.test.config

   ```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

    object Spark2Config extends Serializable{
               System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\hadoop")
               val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("app_name").master("local").getOrCreate()       
    }
   ```