# Spark Windows Installation Java Error

Tags: windows, hadoop, apache-spark, environment-variables, read-eval-print-loop

I am continuing a question from this previous question - [winutils spark windows installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37305001/winutils-spark-windows-installation)
 - and I am aware of this thread - [How to start Spark applications on Windows (aka Why Spark fails with NullPointerException)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32721647/why-does-starting-spark-shell-fail-with-nullpointerexception-on-windows) -, but I haven't found anything that fixes my problem yet.

I am also aware that it has been recommended to build spark from source code with maven or sbt.  I do not want to do that yet, as lot's of people do not build spark from source and it works fine for them.

So far I have set the following environment variables...

```
set _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512M -Xms512M
set _JAVA_OPTION=-Xmx512M -Xms512M
set SPARK_HOME=C:\spark\spark161binhadoop26\bin
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51

::this used to be C:\winutils, but I moved it based on a suggestion
set HADOOP_HOME=C:\spark\spark161binhadoop26\bin

::the scala version here is 2.11.8
set SCALA_HOME=C:\scala\bin

::trying to get through the last warning. The one regarding no IP address
set SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME=localhost
```

and I have ran the command (from the directory of winutils)

```
>winutils.exe chmod 777 /tmp/hive
```

The error I am getting is

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M -Xms512M
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M -Xms512M
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Using Spark's repl log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults-repl.properties
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel("INFO")
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.10.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_51)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
Spark context available as sc.
16/05/19 17:30:21 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.api.jdo" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/C:/spark/spark161binhadoop26/bin/../lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/C:/spark/spark161binhadoop26/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar."
16/05/19 17:30:21 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/C:/spark/spark161binhadoop26/bin/../lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/C:/spark/spark161binhadoop26/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar."
16/05/19 17:30:21 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/C:/spark/spark161binhadoop26/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/C:/spark/spark161binhadoop26/bin/../lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar."
16/05/19 17:30:21 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
16/05/19 17:30:21 WARN Connection: BoneCP specified but not present in CLASSPATH (or one of dependencies)
16/05/19 17:31:17 WARN ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.2.0
16/05/19 17:31:17 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
16/05/19 17:31:18 WARN : Your hostname, DELE5450-16 resolves to a loopback/non-reachable address: fe80:0:0:0:4c1a:cec3:2cd3:a90a%eth13, but we couldn't find any external IP address!
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw-
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.<init>(ClientWrapper.scala:204)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:238)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:218)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive(HiveContext.scala:208)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.functionRegistry$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:462)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.functionRegistry(HiveContext.scala:461)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.UDFRegistration.<init>(UDFRegistration.scala:40)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.<init>(SQLContext.scala:330)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:101)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSQLContext(SparkILoop.scala:1028)
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:15)
        at $iwC.<init>(<console>:24)
        at <init>(<console>:26)
        at .<init>(<console>:30)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:974)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.scala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkILoopInit.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:991)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw-
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:612)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:554)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:508)
        ... 62 more

<console>:16: error: not found: value sqlContext
         import sqlContext.implicits._
                ^
<console>:16: error: not found: value sqlContext
         import sqlContext.sql
```

EDIT:  I updated the error message after changing the path of winutils to be outside of the leaf directory "bin".

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Where is your `winutils.exe` file? Can you paste the absolute path?

Comment: right now it is in "C:\spark\spark161binhadoop26\bin" but I had it before in C:\winutils

Comment: Then your `HADOOP_HOME` variable should be set as `C:\spark\spark161binhadoop26` without the `bin`.

Comment: Thanks I just saw that before you responded haha.  The error I am getting now is a different error, it is "java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw-"  and I have run the command "winutils.exe chmod 777 /tmp/hive" a few times already

Comment: You can try to run `winutils.exe chmod 777 \tmp\hive` instead.

Comment: That didn't work but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Not sure then. This is the permission of the `\tmp\hive` on my machine which works well. *drwxrwxrwx 1 mycomputer mycomputer\None 0 May 19 2016 \tmp\hive*

Comment: how do you check the permissions?

Comment: This command. `winutils.exe ls \tmp\hive`

Comment: man!  it looks good                                                                                          "drwxrwxrwx 1 DELE5450-16\Mark Jones DELE5450-16\None 0 May 18 2016 \tmp\hive"

Comment: although it says May 18 which was yesterday hahaha whut

Comment: Try this command in hadoop\bin "hadoop fs -chmod 777 /tmp/hive"

Comment: Aren't you running on Windows? These are all *Nix commands.

Comment: @Yuval yes Im on windows. These commands are with winutil utility on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually re downloaded the winutils.exe and I left it in another directory at c:/winutils.exe.   I might have downloaded the wrong one because it matters whether you download the 64 bit one vs the 32 bit one.   I wouldn't be too surprised if changing the directory helped but im not sure how it would. 
Please reference my first link "winutils spark windows installation"  for the correct winutils.exe down loads from github

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Psidom in the comments:

```
winutils.exe chmod 777 \tmp\hive
```

is the correct way to correct the permission issue on /tmp/hive, which trigger the initial error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw-
```

(assuming winutils.exe is available in the path)