# Why does spark-shell fail with "'""C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command" on Windows?

Tags: windows, apache-spark

While running the following command prompt I am getting the error as in the screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Command:

```
c:\spark>spark-shell
```

Error:

```
'""C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Why?

Comment: What's your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131

Comment: See the issue? The space? Could you please reinstall Java to some other directory with no space in the path? You could also see if set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131" helps. Open a cmd and do `set` followed by `spark-shell`. Should work.

Comment: But I have wrapped it as, "Program Files", so should the error still arise?

Comment: Can you paste the commands you execute on cmd (not screenshot but the text output) to your question? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah!  But now after after following above steps error occured as  Files"\Java\jdk1.8.0_131"=="x" was unexpected at this time

Comment: I'd like to see the exact commands you execute in cmd (as text not screenshot) and the error message. Thanks

Comment: C:\Users\hp>spark-shell
Output as : Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131""=="x" was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks!  I have posted a same question already

Comment: BTW, can you please set `JAVA_HOME` to `'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131'` (with single quotes not double quotes)? Worth checking out for future readers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [winutils spark windows installation env\_variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37305001/winutils-spark-windows-installation-env-variable)

Answer (score 15):

Suprit,

The issue is most likely with the space in your JAVA_HOME.
If the path contains spaces, use the shortened path name. For example, `C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`

If you are using Windows10. please try the below

```
Set JAVA_HOME as "C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_131"
```

Also make sure you have included `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` in your PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

I *suspect* that you installed Java to a directory with a space so `JAVA_HOME` breaks `spark-shell` script on Windows.

Make sure you install Java to a directory with no space in the path.

---

The other option would be to set `JAVA_HOME` to the same value but wrapped with double quotes, e.g.

```
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131"
```

That will likely lead to the other issue on Windows that was answered in [Why does spark-shell fail with "was unexpected at this time"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44027151/1305344) that's simply to re-install Java to a directory with no space in the path.

---

The thing I could not check out yet would be to wrapped `JAVA_HOME` using single quotes (not double quotes). That in theory would help pass the line with comparison to `"x"`.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue. I uninstalled java and installed in `C:\Java` folder , changed the required env settings and it just worked for me!!!

Answer (score 2):

First you gotta find out where is your JAVA_HOME. In my case it is, "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java"

Then open your file called spark-class2.cmd, locate and change to your java home path (change only the bold text below).

Additional text are included for completeness only.

"**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java**" -Xmx128m -cp "%LAUNCH_CLASSPATH%" org.apache.spark.launcher.Main %* > %LAUNCHER_OUTPUT%
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (%LAUNCHER_OUTPUT%) do (
  echo %%i
  set SPARK_CMD=%%i
)
del %LAUNCHER_OUTPUT%
%SPARK_CMD%

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
It happens with version `spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7` but not with the previous version `spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7`.

Edit line 54 of `spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class2.cmd` by removing the quotes as:

```
set RUNNER=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java
```

Then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere you have set a path or variable without wrapping it in double quotes. Hence the path is being split on the first space.

```
C:\Program Files\Whatever
```

has become...

```
C:\Program
```

To fix it you need to make sure you wrap path variables in double quotes.

i.e

```
C:\Program Files\Whatever\Foo\My Bar\bin
```

should be

```
"C:\Program Files\Whatever\Foo\My Bar\bin"
```

or even better use environment variables for user paths. e.g.

```
"%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Whatever\Foo\My Bar\bin"
"%PROGRAMFILES%\Whatever\Foo\My Bar\bin"
```

Comment: I have added the screenshot of my environment variables path under the link Image2, you may take a look over it

Comment: @SupritGandhi You have it wrong - you need to wrap the whole path - between the semi-colons ';' - i.e. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin" NOT C:\"Program Files" (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin

Comment: Also - just to note I'm pretty sure that isn't the path you need. However like I said originally an unquoted path with spaces is 100% what the problem is.

Comment: Now, the error came as Files"\Java\jdk1.8.0_131"=="x" was unexpected at this time

Comment: Sounds like you perhaps need to ask a separate question? The answer to why "C:\Program' is not recognized" is answered.

Comment: Yeah! I have already asked a separate question now. Btw, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Environment variable to use `spark-shell` from any directory.

Or you need to go inside `bin` folder to execute `spark-shell` command 
in my case its inside `/spark/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/`

Comment: Running spark-shell from any directory gives the same error!

Comment: can you see spark-shell inside bin folder?? and also can you get scala -version ?

Comment: I am unable to get scala -version

Comment: make sure the scala is installed properly.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error after set all path.
So  you have type  Space spark-shell
c:\spark> spark-shell
it will work

Follow to my step

1. Download JDK 8 for windows
2. Install Java Development envioronment
3. Download Spark  with latest version with prebuilt Hadoop
4. Download WinRar for extracting
5. Make folder in C derive put spark folder
6. Go to Conf folder in Spark
7. Change format of log4j.propreties
8. Open Log4 .. in word
9. Replace INFO to Error
10. Save that  file
11. Download Winutils
12. Create new folder as Winutils in C derive
13. Paste download winutils  file in  bin folder
14. Set Environment in Windows
15. Control Panel
16. Click on System and Security
17. System
18. Advance System Setting
19. Environment variables
20. ( Set Spark Home)-New
21. New User_ Variables Form
22. Variable _Name- SPARK_Home
23. Path:- C:\Spark ( Spark foder in C derive)
24. (Set Java Home )- New
25. JAVA_HOME
26. Java Folder path –(1st java folder)
27. Set Hadoop path –
28. HADOOP_HOME
29. Path- C:\Wintulis
30. Path Directories
31. PATH- Edit
32. New- %SPARK_HOME%\bin
33. NEW- %SPARK_HOME%\bin
34. System Environment Done

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the path of spark in the environment variables by following [this](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) or any other tutorials.

Another option is to go into the directory that contains the spark-shell and execute it directly.

Hope this help, Best Regards

Comment: I have set the path of spark in environment variables already, then too the error exists, any other remedy for that?.. By the way, thanks for your solution

Comment: would you please provide us with some useful information that can help us to identify your problem, a screenshot of the output error with what you have entered in the command line at least

Comment: Yeah, I've added the link of the screenshot in the question.

Comment: if you are sure that the environment variable is added correctly, you don't need to go to the spark directory just execute `spark-shell` in the command prompt

Comment: Same error arises, may be my environment variables are having some issue

Comment: So you have to go the bin directory of your spark installation using `cd` command and run the `spark-shell` command

Comment: Tried it, after running spark-shell command anywhere, the error remains same.

Comment: I really couldn't help you in this case, may be an you have an error  with spark installation

Comment: Can you please check my image 2, to check the correctness of path variables?

Comment: and yeah I have set my path in user variable not in system variable, is that the issue?

Comment: the path is not set, you have to put the path of the `bin` directory of your spark folder not the `C:\Programme Files` it will be something like this `spark\spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7\bin`. Please refer to the link I gave you in my answer.