# Spark installation in windows

Tags: apache-spark

I followed all the steps by Frank kane on his Youtube video to install spark on my windows pc. But i get the following error-[image: Error]

I tweaked Environment variables and paths with no luck. My windows version is windows 10.

Comment: Did you run the command inside spark\bin folder ?

Comment: Your spark-shell script has some problem, check the script has unquoted spaces in `C:\Program Files`. Post the content of that file `spark-shell` present inside the C:\Spark folder.

Comment: Yes i also tried to go to the bin folder and try to run it from there but same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does spark-shell fail with "'""C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command" on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44066854/why-does-spark-shell-fail-with-c-program-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update spark path in environment variable list. you can check tutorial to set environment variable.
http://www.dowdandassociates.com/blog/content/howto-set-an-environment-variable-in-windows-command-line-and-registry/

you also need to set path for java and scala to run spark properly.

Comment: I set the environment variables and system path correctly but still error.

Comment: again check env variable path. it seems that you have set path as "c:\Program...." you should set c:\spark

Comment: I added my environment path picture in my original post above.

Comment: also update PATH variable with same path as SPARK_HOME. like c:\spark\bin

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is solved. The problem was with the java installation folder. I installed JDK to its default path which was c:\program files\java\jdk1.8.0_131 , because of that underscore/space spark was not working. Now when i installed jdk on C:\java it worked without a problem. So thanks a lot to those who answered and yes it was a duplicate of the other post which i did not see. the other post was

[Why does spark-shell fail with "'""C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command" on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44066854/why-does-spark-shell-fail-with-c-program-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal)

You can hv a look there too. Same problem , same solution.. thanks..