# install SPARK 2.1.1 on Windows 10

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I want to install Spark 2.1.1 on windows 10, I used a step by step guide mentioned in http://www.eaiesb.com/blogs/?p=334

I did all the steps, but when I come to the last part where I should run the spark-shell and I get the following:

```
C:\>”spark\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7\bin\spark-shell”
```

I keep getting this

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I am running this on Windows 10 machine on a virtual box.
I didn’t have another partition (D is used in the site) so I set it to C:\spark where everything is there (i.e. Hadoop, Spark, and the tmp folders).
UPDATE:/// I reinstalled Java and selected another folder with no spaces within its name, The message that am getting now is (The system cannot find the path specified) 
The environment variables are :

```
JAVA_HOME ——> C:\Java8\jdk1.8.0_131
HADOOP_HOME —–> C:\spark\Hadoop
SPARK_HOME —-> C:\spark\spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7
```

Comment: Its Problem of .. environment variables Not set

Comment: Give the Path Of Bin dir.. in ENV variable. its Solve Your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does spark-shell fail with "'""C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command" on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44066854/why-does-spark-shell-fail-with-c-program-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal)

Comment: I reinstalled Java into a folder that has no space in its name (i.e. Program Files) as some suggested this might be the reason for the error ,,, now the Message I get is  (The system cannot find the path specified)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, before anything, thanks for @RïshïKêsh Kümar on your comments I really appreciate you tried to help me out.
The problem was with Java path, the "location_of_java_folder" didn't work for me, So I just named a folder java8 and reinstalled java in that location, 
oh, and don' forget to restart your machine for changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

> You Have TO Set `Jdk > Bin`Dir Path Like This :

```
JAVA_HOME ——> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin
```

**NOTE:**  If You Set Another Path of File ENV Then You Have TO separate It using Semicolon `;`

**Example:**

```
JAVA_HOME ——> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

Comment: Hello @RïshïKêsh Kümar, I edited my JAVA_HOME system variable as you suggested and still get the same error. but I have a question, several other approaches adds to the path in the user variable, however, this one doesn't, is that normal ?

Comment: Ok.. Now Open `CMD` and Type `Java` i.e  c:/java

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java>Java
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server       to select the "server" VM
                  The default VM is server.

Comment: -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>

Comment: Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options

Comment: -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]

Comment: load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
 
C:\Program Files\Java>

Comment: Am sorry if that was too long but this is what I get when I run this command

Comment: now you can try to install SPARK 2.1.1 on your Windows 10

Comment: Just to clarify things: 1- did you mean editing the path in the (system variables) or in the (user variables) ?.... 2-  under "system variables", I set the value for the JAVA_HOME variable to "C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin"  with the double quotation, I also tried that with single quotation, with no quotation, all the above with full path (i.e. Program Files with the space between program and files) and nothing seems to work.

Comment: it is not working, I reinstalled Java just to solve the space problem in the path, and now I am getting another message (the system cannot find the specified path)

Comment: great.. whose said to remove the java ..now listen you have teamviwer ?

Comment: mail me.. @kumarrishikesh12@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks for the support, I did sent you an email and my teamviewer is ready