# How do I get Spark working on Windows 10 without Hadoop?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I am trying to get Spark running on Windows 10 but I keep running into errors. I have researched thoroughly but I am still running into issues, here is what I have done:

1. Installed JDK 1.8. (works fine)
2. Installed Anaconda3 (works fine)
3. Unzipped Spark 2.3.1
4. Downloaded winutils.exe from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37305001/winutils-spark-windows-installation) and placed it in `.\Hadoop\bin\` (outside of this one file the rest of the Hadoop folder is empty--I was told I did not need Hadoop)
5. Set up enviornment variables as follows:

   1. User Variable : PATH = `.\Continuum\anaconda3`
   2. System Variable :

      - JAVA_HOME = `.\Java\jdk1.8.0_161`
      - HADOOP_HOME = `.\Hadoop`
      - PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON = `jupyter`
      - PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS = `notebook`
      - Path = `.\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin; .\Hadoop\bin; .\spark\bin; .\Hadoop\bin\`
6. I created folder C:\tmp\hive and ran command `winutils.exe chmod -R 777 \tmp\hive`

When I run `pyspark` in the terminal, Jupyter starts fine and runs code. However, the following code keeps breaking. Based on my research I am fairly certain this has to do with my installation.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql.types import Row

records = sc.parallelize([[1, "Alice", 50],[2, "Bob", 80]])

df = records.toDF()
```

Which results in the error:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~\spark\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:

~\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o24.applySchemaToPythonRDD.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw-;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog$lzycompute(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder$$anon$1.<init>(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.analyzer(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$build$2.apply(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder$$anonfun$build$2.apply(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer$lzycompute(SessionState.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.analyzer(SessionState.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.internalCreateDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:577)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.applySchemaToPythonRDD(SparkSession.scala:752)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.applySchemaToPythonRDD(SparkSession.scala:737)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw-
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.newState(HiveClientImpl.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:114)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:385)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw-
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:508)
    ... 45 more


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

AnalysisException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-576476669b32> in <module>()
----> 1 df = records.toDF()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out what worked for me:

I deleted the Hadoop repository with only the winutils.exe and instead downloaded from https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils and made the folder `Hadoop-2.7.1` my `HADOOP_HOME` enviornment variable, then added the bin within that folder to `PATH` and restarted.